# How do I keep my child elements stationary when expanding the navbar?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Currently, when I hover over the navbar, it expands its width, as desired.

However, I don't want my centered icons in the navbar to move along with the expansion. I want them to stay where they are originally.

Here's a visual of what's happening:

[image]

Code:

```
     <div
        id="sidebarContainer"
        className="bg-red-500 lg:w-24 lg:hover:w-44 ease-in duration-300 h-screen flex justify-center items-center group "
      >
        <div
          id="sidebarLinkContainer"
          className="space-y-10 flex flex-col items-center z-10 "
        >
          <div
            id="sidebarHomeDiv"
            className="flex align-center space-x-4 items-center"
          >
            <HomeIcon className="text-white h-7" />
            <p className="text-white hidden group-hover:block ">HOME</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `justify-center` styling from the div tag that has the id of `sidebarContainer` will solve the issue.

Additionally you can add `relative` `left-8` styling or `pl-8`, whatever your preference is to the div that has the id of `sidebarLinkContainer` this should give the div space from the left

like this:

> ```
>    <div
>       id="sidebarContainer"
>       className="bg-red-500 lg:w-24 lg:hover:w-44 ease-in duration-300 h-screen flex items-center group "
>     >
>       <div
>         id="sidebarLinkContainer"
>         className="space-y-10 flex flex-col relative left-8 items-center z-10 "
>       >
>         <div
>           id="sidebarHomeDiv"
>           className="flex align-center text-center space-x-4 "
>         >
>           <HomeIcon className="text-white h-7" />
>           <p className="text-white hidden group-hover:block ">HOME</p>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the right side instead of expanding container

The width for elements will stay the same and container size will increase